# How to load error message in template after submit is triggered, when backend has error

Tags: javascript, angular, components, submit

I have a anuglar 8 application. And I want to show a message after the submit button is triggered.

I have this method:

```
  @ViewChild(IsLoadingComponent, {static: false}) isLoading: IsLoadingComponent;

submit() {
    if (this.sending) {
      return;
    }

    // submit the answers and initialvalues, it is possible that the currentpage has not changed but we save it anyway.
    if (this.isSubmittable()) {
      this.sending = true;

      const answers = this.echeqService.getAnswers();

      this.healthAPI
        .postSingleEcheqSubmission(this.currentEcheqSubmission.id, {
          answers: answers,
          initialValues: {},
          currentPage: this.currentEcheqSubmission.currentPage,
          progress: this.currentEcheqSubmission.progress
        })
        .subscribe(
          results => {
            this.handleSubmitSuccess();
          },
          error => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.handleSubmitError('Vcheq kan niet worden verstuurd');

            }, 1000);
          }
        );
    }
  }
```

and the handleSubmitError looks like this:

```
  handleSubmitError(msg: string) {
    console.log(this.isLoading);
    this.isLoading.displayLoadErrorMessage(msg);
  }
```

and the template of the submit button looks like this:

```
  <div class="echeq-send-button" (click)="submit()" [ngClass]="{ disabled: sending }">
          send <span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin echeqprogress-spinner" *ngIf="sending"></span>
        </div>
```

But so the

isLoading is initialised when the component is loaded.

But when I hit the submit button: this.isloading is undefined:

```
 handleSubmitError(msg: string) {
    console.log(this.isLoading);
    this.isLoading.displayLoadErrorMessage(msg);
  }
```

and I get this error, when I hit submit:

```
core.js:7376 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayLoadErrorMessage' of undefined
    at EcheqProcessComponent.push../src/app/echeq/echeq-process/echeq-process.component.ts.EcheqProcessComponent.handleSubmitError (echeq-process.component.ts:292)
    at echeq-process.component.ts:252
```

So what I have to change? Thank you

I try it like this:

```
  <div class="echeq-send-button" (click)="submit()" [ngClass]="{ disabled: sending }" (error)="handleSubmitError($event)">

          send <span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin echeqprogress-spinner" *ngIf="sending"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Has somebody any advice? Thank you

Comment: What I do wrong then>??

Comment: It's not particularly clear how all of this links together. It was suggested that you create a demo of this when you last asked this 3 hours ago, and I see you still haven't done this. Debugging some plain text is quite hard.

Comment: I cant make demo. There are so  many specific components. I cant include that.But I am very clear. So if you push on the button submit, IsLoadingComponent component is undefined. That is the problem What I also mention

Comment: I can sent you email. Then I can sent more

Comment: But it's not clear. I'm not asking you to copy your whole project it - just recreate the bits that matter. If I had a form with 5000 fields in, I would create a demo that had a form with one field in it to show what the problem was.

Comment: If you post a demo, then anyone can help and offer advice, and it might help other people looking at this question who are also having the same problem

Comment: This isn't a consultancy - it's a Q&A site for people interested in helping other people with specific problems

Answer (score 0):

I solved , like this:

```
 submit() {
    if (this.sending) {
      return;
    }

    // submit the answers and initialvalues, it is possible that the currentpage has not changed but we save it anyway.
    if (this.isSubmittable()) {
      this.eCheqLoaded = false;
      this.eCheqError = false;

      this.sending = true;

      const answers = this.echeqService.getAnswers();

      this.healthAPI
        .postSingleEcheqSubmission(this.currentEcheqSubmission.id, {
          answers: answers,
          initialValues: {},
          currentPage: this.currentEcheqSubmission.currentPage,
          progress: this.currentEcheqSubmission.progress
        })
        .subscribe(
          results => {
            this.handleSubmitSuccess();
          },
          error => {
            this.eCheqLoaded = false;
            this.eCheqError = false;

            setTimeout(() => {
              this.handleSubmitError('vcheq kan niet worden verstuurd')
              //this.isLoading.displayLoadErrorMessage('Vcheq kan niet worden verstuurd');
            }, 500);
          }
        );
    }
  }
```